# PHP Authenticate API

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'd like advice on how to go about in making a PHP API using POST and formats results in JSON (preferably using Laravel). API needs to validate user credentials using these parameters(email address, password, token).

Response 200:

```
{
    "data": [

        {
            "id": 1,
            "email_address": test@gmail.com,
            "authenticated": true,
            "type": password,
            "timestamp": 436543678572,
            "last_login": 436543678572,
            "session_expires": 436543678572
        },
    ],
}
```

Response 200 with SSO:

```
{
    "data": [

        {
            "id": 1,
            "email_address": test@gmail.com,
            "authenticated": true,
            "type": sso,
            "timestamp": 436543678572,
            "last_login": 436543678572,
            "session_expires": 436543678572
        },
    ],
}
```

Comment: You can use either JWT or passport

Answer (score 0):

Easily you can use https://jwt.io (laravel library: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth), put your desired response information on `getJWTCustomClaims` of your user model

```
public function getJWTCustomClaims()
{
    return [
        'user' => [
            'id'     => $this->id,
            'name'   => $this->user_name,
        ]
    ];
}
```

and every where in your frontend layer you can retrive information from the token payload.